# How to exclude class of another project to build or publish in ASP.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, web-config

Is there any way to exclude class of another class Library project to build or publish in ASP.Net application using c#?

Actually I have three project in one solution two is web application and one is class library. I am using class library project in both web application by adding reference. But I want to build web app with only own code of both web app.

Comment: What do you mean with exclude? To make them private? or internal maybe.

Comment: Or probaby you mean "export"?

Comment: @nramirez I think he does not want class to be build...if you make class as private or internal they will be builded

Comment: @CodingDefined cant even image what could be a purpose of excluding a class bytecode from a compled binary. especially in ASP .Net project.

Comment: @MadSorcerer I even cant imagine, @Shabaz You can do something like `<CSFile Include="*.cs" Exclude="YourClassCSFile.cs"/>` in the project file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to solution properties -> Configuration properties. You will see the project and the checkbox for build. You can uncheck if you want other project to exclude from building.

if you want to exclude particular class then only way is to exclude it from the project.

Answer (score 0):

Since you added the reference of class library to the two web projects, I assume you need some kind of code out of that class library.

As a result, if you exclude this reference, your code would not compile and any code that references the library would fail to compile.

I hope I understood your question correct.